# I need a relatively cheap host, which will be able to handle sudden peaks in traffic?

Tags: hosting, cloud-computing, cloud, cloud-hosting

We're launching a product in a few months, which will obviously have a website. Judging from our current traffic, we believe that overall traffic will probably not be that much, but we are aiming at promoting the site heavily using social media.

This has the typical problem, that IF we get suddenly get picked up by a large tech blog, we will see a sudden burst: A very heavy increase in traffic all of the sudden. If we use a cheap charlie host as our current host is (www.unoeuro.com) or something similar like GoDaddy, I'm afraid that the site will go down under the load. If that happens, then we might as well have thrown our social media marketing dollars out of the window.

Our site will be relatively lightweight, all videos hosted at Youtube or Vimeo and other than that mainly just a standard webpage (ie nothing too heavy).

I am hoping for recommendations for a good hosting company, which has some form of scalable hosting, so if / when a traffic surge hits, the site will not go down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, TANSTAAFL applies.  There are some technology-specific hosting companies that can do quick scaling, but in general you need to have good systems engineering people on hand (either hired directly, or at your disposal indirectly through your hosting provider), and that costs money.  Cost/benefit calculations, all that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Gandi.net hosting](http://www.gandi.net/hosting/). They're a French domain registrar and cloud hoster. I've been a happy customer for years.

Their hosting platform allows you to upgrade or downgrade the amount of 'shares' manually, or based on a schedule, automatically on demand, or whatever. Their system is modern, full-featured, and reasonably priced.

Comment: Adding shares doesn't help if your application isn't architected to be able to take advantage of them.

Comment: I'm not talking about separate instances. They increase the resources of your current instance. This will, in most applications, increase performance.

Answer (score -1):

You can also consider Amazon Web Services (AWS), which can handle sudden changes in load - the EC2 service, Elastic Compute 2. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/